# How can I send http request with get attributes?

Tags: android, http, get, request

What i mean is that i want to send an http request to my server like:

> http://blahblah.blah/index.php**?command=make**

in android

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like :

**Http Post:**

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://blahblah.blah/index.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "make"));        
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

**Http Get**

```
HttpResponse response = null;
try {    
        // Create http client object to send request to server     
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Create URL string
        String URL = "http://blahblah.blah/index.php?command=make";
        // Create Request to server and get response
        HttpGet httpget= new HttpGet();
        httpget.setURI(new URI(URL));
        response = client.execute(httpget);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Comment: This is an HTTP Post.  The question is for an HTTP GET

Comment: i used your get method and my app crashes every time i push the button

Comment: I have updated Http Get in my answer. Hope it works for you now, as it is working for me. :)

Comment: Note: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated, by now. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802365/replacement-for-deprecated-defaulthttpclient

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by setting the URL to be that when you use URL Connection

```
// you can pass mUrl as http://blahblah.blah/index.php?command=make and if you are expecting a returned value, you can compare that with successVal

public static boolean checkSuccess(String mUrl, String successVal)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(mUrl);
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        ucon.setReadTimeout(5000);
        is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(300);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
        {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        String success = new String(baf.toByteArray());

        return success.equals(successVal);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (is != null)
            {
                is.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```