# GET request in Android

Tags: android

### How to append the URL with (key,value) pair before making a get request

- i am passing `restaurant name` from the previous activity as
  `Intents`
- I am storing that value in variable `restaurant_name`

---

*Now how can i pass the value stored in variable `restaurant_name` to the `url` as a (Key,value) before i make a get request*

---

**Restaurantdesc.java**

```
public class RestaurantDesc extends Activity{
    // url to make request


    private static String url = "http://***********************";


    String restaurant_name ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray first_array ;
    JSONArray second_array;
    TextView textView;
    TextView text;
    TextView topdisp;

    private SparseArray<String> startarsMap = new SparseArray<String>();
    private SparseArray<String> saladsMap = new SparseArray<String>();
    private SparseArray<String> maincourseMap = new SparseArray<String>();
    private SparseArray<String> desertMap = new SparseArray<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_desc);

        //url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        restaurant_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");



        topdisp=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarRestaurantDescActivityName);
        Button BACKBUTTON=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarRestaurantDescActivityBackButton);
        BACKBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emp1=new Intent(RestaurantDesc.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(emp1);
            }
        });


        Button PHOTOBUTTON=(Button) findViewById(R.id.RestaurantPhotosButton);
        PHOTOBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent pht=new Intent(RestaurantDesc.this,RestaurantPhotos.class);
                pht.putExtra("key", getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));

                startActivity(pht); 
            }
        });



        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(RestaurantDesc.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();
    }




    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantDesc.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);





        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String _response = null;
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

                //url = url."?Key=restaurant_name";
                //url += "?" + "key=" + restaurant_name;


                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url=url += "?" + "Key=" + restaurant_name);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                _response =EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
                first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RestaurantNAME");
```

<------------------- rest of code------------------------>
    }

Comment: Is your code relevant to the question?

Comment: Yes i am refering to variables in the posted code itself

Comment: You found already a good place to do it, where exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: You mention a string, yes, but you haven't even made a GET request. Have you looked at any examples/tutorials?

Comment: @ henry.....before i make the Get request from this code i need to append the url with what i have mentioned but ...... dont know how to do it

Comment: how about `url += "?" + "key=" + restaurant_name;` ?

Comment: Maybe you could try "volley" !!!!

Comment: @ SatelliteSD ...... tried the solution .... but i get the error above

Comment: use this way url += "?" + "key=" + restaurant_name;

Comment: @Piyush ........ I made but no change ... i have even poste main activity also ... please check whether i am passing the intents correctly

Comment: @smriti..... why are you calling intent in preExecute() method of button click event...?

Comment: That iam doing to navigate back to mainActivity !

Comment: But in instead of using in preExecute method you can use on oncreate() method...

Comment: I did it but... still why i am not able to append my parameters to get request ... i am not able to identify ... I am passing intents correctly from mainactivity to this activity :(

Comment: And which one is your first activity????

Comment: Oh...its a good...But it is with your help not mine....Good Luck..!!

Comment: Ok.............nope...

Comment: Please check your mail .... :)

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383614/1554935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the key value pair to the `url`

```
if(!url.endsWith("?"))
    url += "?";

List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key1", "value1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key2", "value2"));

String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

url += paramString;
```

And now pass this `url` to your get request..

I Referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [this](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.hu/2011/01/android-create-url-using.html) solution:

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("http://www.yoursite.com:12345").buildUpon();

b.path("/path/to/something/");
b.appendQueryParameter("arg1", String.valueOf(42));

if (username != "") {
  b.appendQueryParameter("username", username);
}

String url = b.build().toString();
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: `Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse(url); b.appendQueryParameter("Key", restuarant_name); ` and at doBackgroundAction()`HttpGet request = new HttpGet(b.build.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, like this:

```
 http://54.218.73.244:7004/RestaurantDesc?keyname1=value1&keyname2=value2&keyname3=value3...
```

and so on

***UPDATE***

```
private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7004/RestaurantDesc";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String _response = null;
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

            //url = url."?Key=restaurant_name";
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url+"?Key="+restaurant_name);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            _response =EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
            first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RestaurantNAME");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```