# Hitting a get/post request a URL in android but no request is recieved at server side

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to put a get/post request on link
http://103.48.108.35:5005/dataitsno
but no request is pinging on my server 
I'm using following code on my android application.
I also want to send it in background request(does not hamper current process).

```
public  void  SendCont() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
String Name="Raj";
        String OwnNo="85859657";
        String text="";
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("owndat","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(OwnNo, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("cont", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try
        {

            URL url = new URL("http://103.48.108.35:5005/dataitsno?quer='"+OwnNo+"'");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
        //content.setText( text  );
    }
```

Comment: Probably you are getting exception,so try to print exception in your catch blocks.

Comment: no it is not putting any exception, so if I'm doing right thing then why it is not hitting the url, and if I'm wrong, What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: are you sending POST request or GET ?
If you are sending request using post,you can't send the variables appending to the url.

Comment: Or can you give me a solution for this I just need working code to hit a URL in android in this scenario.http://103.48.108.35:5005/dataitsno

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383614/2110050 make sure you have added Internet permission

Comment: But how will I use it in Intent service and in meanwhile let me try with the link you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help u,

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    URL url = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query

                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

                    // u can read data here
                    stream.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

& the convertStreamToString is,

```
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

Comment: can you merge answer you gave with method at following link so it can run in background? 
Code is at:
http://app4pc.com/static/comment/androidCode.txt