# Android HTTP Get Old Library

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an android program to send a HTTP Get Request to another device on the network. However, all the tutorials I can find on doing this are using old libraries no longer supported by the Android Studio. Could somebody point me in the direction of the library I want to import to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29058727/115145 http://stackoverflow.com/q/29294479/115145 http://stackoverflow.com/q/31802365/115145 ...

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how the requests are handled on the server, you might be interested in [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)