# Send data to webservice from android using or Get request method

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin.android, androidhttpclient, android-webservice

I want to send data from the app i'm building to a web service once its deployed and launched. How do I do that using either the get method or post method?

For instance: Get(String phone, String message) {}
with the url:
www.rbuildit.azurewebsites.net/api/HomeChurch/SendReport?phone=000000000000&text=99999

Please help I'm quite confused. Thanks

Comment: Use [retfoit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). It's a type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java.

Comment: retrofit? ok thanks @ Merhawi

Comment: Also I just want to send data to the server and not receive a response

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383614/4688650) for simple requests. Retrofit is an advanced library

Comment: Yea I saw tha, but httpClient doesn't work for sdk 23 and above